# input.nextLine() does not wait for input, and runs a method immediately

Tags: java, string, loops, input

I'm doing a program which allows me to de-code resistor values into colours.However even after searching for solutions online, I still do not get why I could not fix it. I just learned this for about 4 months so I'm quite an amateur in this.

It's supposed to run like: Menu>Select1>FirstColour>Selection>SecondColour>Selection>FourthColour>Selection>FifthColour>Selection>ShowDecodedColour>LoopToMenu.

But when I select 1 in the menu,I immediately get "Enter the number for the first colour strip : Invalid Number Please Re-Enter Your Number : "

I checked the value of my int activator and it is always -1.

Please help!

My code:http://pastebin.com/ezVHLxYj

This is the working code, but because it is crashable, the professor has asked me to use switch function instead of else-if, and a few more issues like converting String to Int to prevent errors in reading inputs:http://pastebin.com/6YM4ztZXo

Comment: IMO there's too much code... one tip though: change the `switch` statement to simply: `four[k] = OneColour[activator];`

Comment: [**Read this post**](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/), it's a common mistake when using `nextInt()` before `nextLine()`

Comment: @alfasin haha yea it's my project for programming so the prof is expecting programmer's quality work :( hmm yea I get your idea. I used the switch function so if the number is invalid,regardless of characters or numbers, it will print "Invalid". Is there a way to follow up your method?

Comment: @Christian Thanks! that worked! Though I still receive invalid message despite me entering the right numbers :(

Comment: Yes, use try/catch: `try{ a = Integer.parseInt(choices);} catch(NumberFormatException e){ a = -1;} finally{ return a;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because `nextInt()` doesn't read the new-line character entered by user (when he pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Therefore, this new-line character stays in the buffer and the `nextLine()` method consumes it. That's why it looks like the `nextLine()` is being skipped. For further information please visit this post: [Using nextInt() before nextLine()](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/).

**Notes:**

In `switch(choices) ...`, the lines

```
a = Integer.parseInt("0");
```

could be simply replaced by

```
a = 0;
```

similar for each case.